# Add I18n translations to rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How can i add a translation test to my specs ? Something like :

```
flash[:error].should == I18n.translate 'error.discovered'
```

this does not work of course. How to make it work ?

I want to make sure that i get a certain error back.

Comment: try app.t('error.discovered') really dont have a clue but maybe you are lucky :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In my code, a Rails 3 project, using RSpec 2, that is exactly the line I write:

```
describe "GET 'index'" do
  before do
    get 'index'
  end
  it "should be successful" do
    response.should be_redirect
  end

  it "should show appropriate flash" do
    flash[:warning].should == I18n.t('authorisation.not_authorized')
  end
end
```

So I am not sure why you say it is not possible?

Comment: :O:O Your syntax works ! Mine wouldn't. I guess if you do it like i did, you will get an error as well. Don't know why that is happening, but that is indeed the solution !

Comment: Could have been a case of missing parens around the right hand side of the assertion.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this is optimal, but in my Rails3/RSpec2 apps, I test all my locale translations in RSpec in the following way:

I set the available locales in my **config/initializers/i18n.rb** file:

```
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :it, :ja]
```

and in my spec files that need translation checking I have tests that looks something like:

```
describe "Example Pages" do   

  subject { page }

  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|

    describe "example page" do
      let(:example_text) { t('example.translation') }

      before { visit example_path(locale) }

      it { should have_selector('h1', text: example_text) }
      ...
    end
    ...   
  end
end
```

I wasn't sure how to get just the `t()` method to be usable in the specs without needing `I18n.t` so I just added a small convenience method to **spec/support/utilities.rb**:

```
def t(string, options={})
  I18n.t(string, options)
end
```

**Update**: These days I tend to use the [i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) gem to handle testing related to i18n, and not what I wrote above or have answered on StackOverflow previously.

I wanted to use i18n in my RSpec tests primarily to make sure that I had translations for everything ie there were no translations missed.  i18n-tasks can do that and more through static analysis of my code, so I don't need to run tests for all `I18n.available_locales` anymore (apart from when testing very locale-specific functionality, like, for example, switching from any locale to any other locale in the system).

Doing this has meant I can confirm that all i18n keys in the system actually have values (and that none are unused or obsolete), while keeping the number of repetitive tests, and consequently the suite running time, down.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the code in the controller is:

```
flash[:error] = I18n.translate 'error.discovered'
```

You could stub 'translate':

```
it "translates the error message" do
  I18n.stub(:translate) { 'error_message' }
  get :index # replace with appropriate action/params
  flash[:error].should == 'error_message'
end
```

Comment: This is not practical really, since i will have to pass the error message text. I would want to just pass the translation identifier error.discovered.

Comment: In this case you don't want to test whether the translation library works, only whether your controller code calls the translate method and assigns the translation to `flash[:error]`. The method stub replaces `I18n.translate` and returns the value passed in the block -- the error message text itself doesn't matter, it can be anything you like.

Comment: I actually want to check if the message of flash[:error] is the expected translated message. The reason i wan to do this is for fear of mixing it with other flash[:error] messages in my rspec tests. For instance, i may check if user has gold and pass the test of flash[:error] should not be nil. Although the test succeeded, it could be that another previous error was flashed. It actually happened and was lucky enough to discover it :/

Comment: No problem, just set the return value of the stub to some arbitrary text that cannot be confused with another error message. You don't want to use the actual translation because 1) you'd need to test each locale; 2) it would make the tests brittle

Comment: But if i stub the translation with my own message, i'm actually checking the translation process right ? I don't want to do that. I want to see if the correct error message was flashed. Or maybe some previous check populated the error variable( i tend to use :error for my flashes). Am i missing something ?

Comment: i was actually looking for a way, if there is, to make i18n work for rspec, like it works for the controller. If that is possible, of course.

Comment: No, stubbing the translate method does not check the translation process, it replaces the method with another one that simply returns a string. RSpec resets the value of `flash` for each test, so the values you assign in previous tests should not carry over to the current one. If you're concerned about that, you could add `flash[:error].should be_nil` before calling the controller action, just to be sure.

Comment: aaa, i see the point. So, i could have a before :each and reset it to nil every time right ?

Comment: Well, you should not have to do that -- RSpec should clear out the `flash` hash for each new example. If it is not doing so, something is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, yes, this seems like the correct behavior. But it's not happening and that is what led me to ask that. I get occasions where previous flashes are checked. Could it be because i'm using context do for these tests ? I am not sure why, but it happens.

Comment: @zetetic do you think that stubbing i18n in integration specs is worth it? I believe it doesn't change much in terms of performance but gives test much more value. What do you think? Do you stub i18n in integration tests?