# how to test i18n in Rails with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rspec-rails

**Question context:**

let say that there is some really important row in **config/locales/en.yml** that is crucial to exist.

```
en:
  foo:
    bar: "bubla!"
```

- I don't want to test every single line  but
- I don't want the test to be too brittle (so no I18n.t('foo.bar').should =~ /bubla/)

so way I'm testing currently is like this

```
#spec/locals_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'
describe I18n do
  it do
    I18n.t('date.datepicker').should be_kind_of(String)
  end
end
```

this way I'm just ensuring that translation exist and that it don't continues (e.g. 'foo.bar.car.lol'

but still I'm not satisfied

**Question:** What's the best practice to test I18n translations with RSpec and where in spec folder I should place them ?

Comment: after @Paul answer I refactor to: 
  it {I18n.available_locales.each{|locale|  I18n.t('date.datepicker').should be_kind_of(String) }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5415158/567863) for some ideas.  My preferred way is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671020/567863) on the same question.

**Update**: These days I tend to use the [i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) gem to handle testing related to i18n, and not what I wrote above or have answered on StackOverflow previously.

I wanted to use i18n in my RSpec tests primarily to make sure that I had translations for everything ie there were no translations missed.  i18n-tasks can do that and more through static analysis of my code, so I don't need to run tests for all `I18n.available_locales` anymore (apart from when testing very locale-specific functionality, like, for example, switching from any locale to any other locale in the system).

Doing this has meant I can confirm that all i18n keys in the system actually have values (and that none are unused or obsolete), while keeping the number of repetitive tests, and consequently the suite running time, down.

Comment: hey, thanx for answer but in general your solution is same as @Phoet described in post below, please read my comment, however I like the idea of looping trought   *I18n.available_locales.each*  +1 for that

Comment: @equivalent8, it's a bit late, but hope my update serves in offering up another alternative to testing i18n.  If you have learned anything else since your last update to this question, please share!

Answer (score -1):

i think that i would write an acceptance test for such a "crucial" thing.

in most cases you need the translation in some specific context, ie. displaying something in a datepicker. i would test that context using capybara or whatever works with a javascript driver.

just testing that this translation exists is useless if you don't have the context that it's used within.

Comment: You get the context right just from reading keyword "datapicker" :) ...let say I have helper that will handle all the rendering of the datepicker inputs. I already created helper spec to check if all the stuff is present. But I'm stubbing I18n to return dummy value I18n.stub(:t){'exampleformat'}  .... so this way I'm sure that html context is rendered correctly, It's just actual translation I'm worried about  ... source at https://gist.github.com/3053409  helper is at the bottom