# using Rspec and internationalization with nice routing (current_path.should == new_post_path )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rspec, rails-routing

I'm creating a multilanguage CMS with Rails, Rspec (for test) and capybara.

the problem appear when i wrote this test

```
it "redirect and create a new post" do
  visit posts_path
  create_new_post = I18n.t('posts.index.create_new_post')
  click_link create_new_post
  current_path.should == new_post_path
end
```

problem is in last line and i got this
    expected: "/posts/new"
         got: "/en/posts/new" (using ==)

i want to use something like "new_post_path", not "/en/posts/new"

the main problem depicted when i use something like this

```
it "redirect to show link" do
  visit posts_path
  page.should have_content 'show'
  click_link 'show'

  current_path.should == post_path(@post)
end
```

any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5415158/567863) for some ideas on this subject. My preferred way is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671020/567863) on the same question.  But, using your current code, to get your expectations right you would perhaps do something like this (assuming you want to test all of your locales):

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|

  it "should redirect and create a new post" do
    visit posts_path(locale)
    create_new_post = I18n.t('posts.index.create_new_post')
    click_link create_new_post
    current_path.should == new_post_path(locale)
  end

  it "should redirect to show link" do
    visit posts_path(locale)
    page.should have_content 'show'
    click_link 'show'

    current_path.should == post_path(locale, @post)
  end
end
```