# Running Rails tests multiple times for I18n testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, internationalization

Is it possible to wrap every single test created for a Rails website to make them run multiple times, each time with a slight change to global config?  Specifically I want to be able to do:

```
For all supported languages
  Set I18n language to <next language>
  Run all tests
```

Since my tests fail if, for example, there is no French translation of 'Hello', I can then use this to at least confirm that 'something' exists in the French variant (although I don't, of course, know it's not 'au revoir' :-) ).

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5415158/567863) may be of reference to you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need a way to set `I18n.locale` in your app from ENV. Then you can write a rake task or a plain Ruby script which will iterate over the list of your available locales and will run specs with the specified locale in ENV.

Cheers!